# Python cffi module: does verify() require re-compiling the entire c library I want to use from my python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffi, python-cffi

Say I need to use a few functions from a shared library, e. g. libfoo.so, from python code. I figured the cffi module could help me, especially as it seems to support opaque types if one uses the `verify()` function.

I did not fully understand though, what the [documentation](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/%23what-actually-happened) means by

> verify() [...] is an alternative: instead of doing a dlopen, it generates and compiles a piece of C code.

Do I have to recompile the entire libfoo.so? Or just a certain part (relevant parts of the header)? If the latter is the case, is this significantly less of a hassle in terms of dependencies, configuration options, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ffi.verify() (as well as ffi.set_source() in the soon-to-be-released cffi 1.0) generates and compiles a lightweight C wrapper which calls your existing library.  The C wrapper contains regular C code that calls the library functions, so as usual with C, the library doesn't need to be recompiled in order to be used---but, also as usual with C, you need to have the headers of that library installed (typically from a package called something like `libfoo-dev` from your OS distribution).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So I am right to assume that compiling this 'wrapper' only needs the header files of the libfoo library, but not all the dependencies which were initially needed to compile libfoo?